# How to Compare json Object value in Xml within Mulesoft

Tags: json, xml, dataweave, mulesoft

My Json Payload is

```
[
    {
        "Customer Contacted": "Rupesh",
        "Inspected": "Mahesh",
        "Lost": "Fire",
        "Job Start Date": "",
        "Work Complete": "",
        "Billing Complete": ""
    }
]
```

My XML is

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml 
---

    {
        root: {
            CustomerContacted: if(payload."Customer Contacted"=="Rupesh") "Hari" 
            else null,
            Inspected: if(payload."Inspected"=="Mahesh")"vamsi"
            else null,
            Lost: payload.Lost,
            JobStartDate: payload."Job Start Date",
            WorkComplete: payload."Work Complete",
            BillingComplete: payload."Billing Complete"
        }
    }
```

If the values matches from Payload and value provided in If Condition then the value should be changed.
After Transformation i am getting below Output.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
  <CustomerContacted/>
  <Inspected/>
  <Lost>Fire</Lost>
  <JobStartDate></JobStartDate>
  <WorkComplete></WorkComplete>
  <BillingComplete></BillingComplete>
</root>
```

I am getting null Values in Customer contacted and Inspected fields but i am expecting the values "Rupesh" and "Mahesh" as "Hari" and "Vamsi"

Kindly let me know what needs to be changed in the XML Code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The payload is an array and to match the element to a string, you need to define the index. For example, on your payoad, the `Customer Contacted` is part of the object and your payload type is an array.

The syntax should be like:

```
if(payload."Customer Contacted"[0] == "Rupesh") "Hari" 
   else null
```

Example:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
{
        root: {
            CustomerContacted: if(payload."Customer Contacted"[0] == "Rupesh") "Hari" 
            else null,
            Inspected: if(payload."Inspected"[0]=="Mahesh")"vamsi"
            else null,
            Lost: payload.Lost[0],
            JobStartDate: payload."Job Start Date"[0],
            WorkComplete: payload."Work Complete"[0],
            BillingComplete: payload."Billing Complete"[0]
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ray A, thanks for the update now the code is working.And i would like to know if the input field value is null.Suppose "Rupesh" is null then i don't want to display this CustomerContacted: if(payload."Customer Contacted"[0] == "Rupesh") "Hari" else null, line in the output.

Comment: To output a field based on a condition you add the condition to the end of the line so for CustomerContacted line you would update to be like this: `(CustomerContacted: if(payload."Customer Contacted"[0]=="Rupesh") "Hari" else null) if (!isEmpty(payload."Customer Contacted"[0])),`

Answer (score 3):

Since your input is an array you need to iterate over it to get the values or hardcode the index with array notation [0].  I'd recommend using the `map` function since hardcoding an index is not extendable in case you get an input array where the size is greater than 1. Something like the following  should work for this case:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml 
---
root: {
    subroot: payload map {
        CustomerContacted: if($."Customer Contacted"=="Rupesh") "Hari" else null,
        Inspected: if($."Inspected"=="Mahesh") "vamsi" else null,
        Lost: $.Lost,
        JobStartDate: $."Job Start Date",
        WorkComplete: $."Work Complete",
        BillingComplete: $."Billing Complete"
    }
}
```

Note: you need the `subroot` field to output in the case of multiple items in the input array otherwise will get error: `Trying to output second root` because of invalid xml structure that would result.